# use color resource to change string resource in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

I want to change the color of a string resource using a color resource. Is that doable? The following is not working.

```
<string name="share_action"><font fgcolor="@color/primary">share</font></string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prior to 4.x, you could do this:

```
<string name="error"><font fgcolor="#ff9a1d1d">Error!</font></string>
```

However, bug `https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58192` broke this functionality because it introduced an integer parser that can't handle numbers with the highest bit set, and unfortunately you can't omit the opacity part of the color (which most people would prefer to set to ff as in this example.)